# jQuery UI Combobox dropdown not moving when window is resized

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, browser

I have set up a jQuery UI combobox with the following HTML:

```
 <select id="myDropdown" ></select>
```

and this javascript:

```
function populateDropdown(data)
{
    renderDropDown($("#myDropdown"), data, onDropdownChange, null);
}
```

and

```
 function renderDropDown($control, items, callback, selectedCode) {
        $control.find("option").remove();
        $.each(items, function (i, item) {
            $control.append((item.code === selectedCode ? OPTION_TEMPLATE_SELECTED : OPTION_TEMPLATE)(item));
        });
        $control.combobox().off("change").on("change", callback);
        $(".ui-combobox-input ").off("keydown").on("keydown", disableBackspace);
    }
```

This works absolutely fine until you have the dropdown opened and then resize the window.
The items within the open part of the dropdown remain exactly where they were on the screen whilst the browser resizes around it.

[image]

I've tried hooking into the windows.resize event and hiding the items and also removing the items within the dropdown, but that doens't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you post your code to move the dropdown list when window is resized?

Comment: I have no code to move the dropped down section of the dropdownlist. Simply closing the list or hiding the dropped down section would suffice

Comment: If you post your code of how you create your dropdown element (HTML and JS) I can answer you a solution to move your dropdown list when window is resized. If you're looking for a better solution, I'm not your man :D